# Automate Word plug-ins

Tags: c#, plugins, automation, ms-office, office-interop

We are planning to automate the different plug-ins available in a Word document.

Using C#, we need to interact with textbox, buttons and other controls available in a given plug-in. Is there any way to automate this?

The solution should work with both Word 2003 & 2007.

Comment: What do you mean by "Automate"? Is this something Word specific?

Comment: Yes Pekka, we have one application in which few plug-ins have been placed in word document. We wish to provide a solution to automate these plug-ins so that automation team can automate their functional word based scenarios.

Comment: Is this your own add-in or a third-party one?

Comment: It's mix of both. few addin-ins are third party and few are developed in house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Check out the Office Open XML as well as the Office API's</strike>

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840817

Sorry for the irrelevant link, I read through it and thought it was an overview for Word API. Here is a more relevant link about interacting with Word programattically.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am checking out the applicability of information available on link

Comment: That link seems totally unrelated to the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @0xA3 I've updated the link to a what I had originally thought